# Possible to access large data structures loaded in another process from C#?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I have an application that runs many threads in parallel, each which process the same hundreds of GB of read-only, never changing data in different ways. Even with ZeroFormatter, it takes time to load all of the data into memory before kicking off each run. I'd like to eliminate this wait.

In C#, would it be possible for one process to load data into memory and keep it around persistently, and have another process, launched later, efficiently access the data in-place?

Edit:

OK my apologies for not including enough relevant information. I'm processing sequential, time-series data on very powerful hardware with half a terabyte of memory. So far, streaming the data off of the disk and processing it incrementally, which is normally the way to go, is slower than loading it all up front first because the process is not CPU constrained, but memory-to-CPU bandwidth constrained. I wanted to just keep it all in memory and skip the step that takes the most time.

I'm tempted to withdraw the question, or at least mark a comment as the answer. If process to process memory access is very slow, than there really is no way to speed it up further because I'm already partitioning the data by NUMA core.

Comment: That's what database servers do. Or Redis. Databases will probably run *faster* because they take advantage of indexing and efficient algorithms. In any case, cross-process access is always slow due to marshalling between isolated memory spaces, security checks etc.

Comment: Frankly, it would be better if you used *asynchronous* code to process the data while loading instead of waiting to load everything before processing. You can create a processing pipeline using TPL Dataflow or channels from the System.Threading.Channels namespace, feed data to the head block and have the rest of the blocks process that data in separate threads

Comment: `this is time-series data processed sequentially` that's a perferct scenario for a processing pipeline, perhaps combined with Reactive Extensions.

Comment: If you have hundreds of GB of data, you're going to struggle to store that all in memory unless you have as much (or more) RAM. A producer-consumer pattern, where one thread loads data and another processes it as it becomes available, is ideal in this situation. Also consider scaling your processing job out. Configure your application so that it will only process certain data ranges if requested. Then, you can copy your application and the relevant data to cheap cloud VM instances and aggregate the results after all worker VMs have finished.

Comment: Yes we talked about clustering, but I have a machine with hundreds of GB worth of RAM and hundreds of processors specifically built for what I'm doing. I'm in the process of wringing out all the performance I can out of it, including making sure memory access respects how NUMA nodes work. So this really isn't an X/Y problem, I really do want to persist the data set into memory. Suggesting using a database with indexes instead... madness.

Comment: If you really want to wring out the last bit of performance, you should  be using C or C++.   C# is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @Neil on the contrary, using the *correct* algorithm and *reducing* allocations, using the *correct* architecture  can improve performance by orders of magnitude. Simply switching languages won't improve performance, handle parallelism (how would you do *that* in C++? )

Comment: @PJ7 you didn't provide *any* information about the problem. As for madness, you're waiting for IO to complete before you can even start processing now, on a data set that could be processed one event at a time as it gets loaded. That's what Netflix and all cloud event analytics offerings do. And Lenovo sells standalone database servers with TB of RAM for at least two years now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How would you do parallelism in C++ ? Erm, use CreateThread etc, like C# does.

Comment: @PJ7 *Cross-process* communication *is* expensive enough to shock though.

Comment: @Neil no and no (and no on `CreateThread`, until recently C++ didn't have a standard thread type). That's not parallelism. *Parallelism* means taking a big data set, splitting it into partitions and then using *one* worker to work on each partition at full speed, without locking or synchronization. In C# that's done using Parallel.ForEach or PLINQ.

Comment: @Neil in C++ there are worker libraries too, but not yet in the standard itself. *Time-series* analysis on the other hand can use *pipelines* of independent workers, each processing one message/event at a time and sending it to the next one.  That's how Reactive Extensions work.

Comment: Since I was writing multi-threaded C++ code on Windows in the mid 90s,who cares about 'standard' thread types.

Comment: @Neil people that don't want *threads*, they want efficient many-core parallelism, SIMD, vectorization. Which manual threading won't offer

Comment: @Neil I've worked on multithreaded C++ code since the 90s. But I've also worked on algorithmic trading and plain-old threading won't process 500GB of data on a 64-core machine efficiently. Add Microsoft's concrurrency runtime and you get a x64 improvement, simply by using efficient workers. *And* it processes the data while loading it

Comment: @PJ7 you didn't explain the problem so I'll guess it's algorithmic trading, with multiple models on the same data. I've dealt with the same problem in the past by creating multiple "workers", one or more per model, and feeding them the input file, often the same message events to each one. If you use separate dataflow blocks for different processing steps, possibly with a large DOP per block, you process a lot of data at the speed you're reading them. The specifics matter a lot of course, and many operations can't work until they consume the entire data set (eg medians)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos yeah maybe you're familiar with the problem when the data's being processed faster than it loads, which is why right now I'm loading it all up front because any streaming process I've tried is simply slower.

Comment: @PJ7 IPC is slow, no matter the technology - that's the baseline fact. Trying to access data across processes has an overhead no matter the technique you use, that's why you should *avoid* it if you can. Why don't you put everything in *one* process? If you can't, you need to access data in chunks big enough to spread the cost. Other than that, you're essentially asking for Redis

Comment: @PJ7 I've encountered the problem when only 1 core in a 64-core machine was busy but that was due to inappropriate C++ coding. Instead of trying to load one file at a time, I changed the code to use 64 different workers and pump files to them. The partitioning was per symbol, with the first step deciding which worker to send each file to. Unfortunately, the boss was so happy by the x64 times improvement, he didnd't see any reason for more optimizations. This worked because disk IO is cached at multiple levels, allowing parallel loading even from a "single" disk array

Comment: @PJ7 besides, nothing prevents the blocks in a pipeline from caching the data they load, either in BufferBlocks or concurrent collections, allowing them to be used again, or fed to *other* pipelines.

Comment: @PJ7 in any case, the available IPC mechanisms are described in [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). Most of them are network-based or meant for light data loads. Only *shared memory* mapped files actually share memory locations, but beware- *DON'T* base them on a real file - that's explained in [Sharing files and memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) . To share *memory* you need to pass an `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: @PJ7 in C#, you'd need the [MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createnew?view=netcore-3.0) or [CreateOrOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createoropen?view=netcore-3.0) methods. Again, this isn't as cheap as local data and the code you need to marshal the data will add its own overhead, so you should benchmark your code using BenchmarkDotNet

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).  The basic premise is that, each process 'thinks' it's loading it's own file, but in reality, they are all using the same physical view.

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes
    long length = 0x20000000; // 512 megabytes

    // Create the memory-mapped file.
    using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data", FileMode.Open,"ImgA"))
    {
        // Create a random access view, from the 256th megabyte (the offset)
        // to the 768th megabyte (the offset plus length).
        using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
        {
            int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor));
            MyColor color;

            // Make changes to the view.
            for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
            {
                accessor.Read(i, out color);
                color.Brighten(10);
                accessor.Write(i, ref color);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public struct MyColor
{
public short Red;
public short Green;
public short Blue;
public short Alpha;

// Make the view brighter.
public void Brighten(short value)
{
    Red = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Red + value);
    Green = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Green + value);
    Blue = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Blue + value);
    Alpha = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Alpha + value);
}
}
```